# How to handle event for nonvisual objects in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events

I am trying to perform two way binding e.g I have a button (out of many controls), on its selection, I am showing the values of its diff properties(like height, width etc) in some textinput. This one way process works fine.

But the reverse process doesn't work. i.e When I select some button, and try to change its dimension by entering some value in height, width textinputs, the dimension are not changed.

How to know which button was selected by me? How events needs to be handled here ?

---

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create some data and bind it to the grid
            dt1 = GetData(1000, 3);
            this.UltraGrid1.DataSource = dt1;
            //Set the grid's CreationFilter to a new instance of the NumbersInRowSelectors class. 
            this.UltraGrid1.CreationFilter = new NumbersInRowSelectors();           
        }

        private void UltraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
        {       
            //Hide the default images that are drawn in the RowSelectors, like the pencil and asterisk, etc. 
            e.Layout.Override.RowSelectorAppearance.ImageAlpha = Infragistics.Win.Alpha.Transparent;

            //Center the text in the RowSelectors.
            e.Layout.Override.RowSelectorAppearance.TextHAlign = Infragistics.Win.HAlign.Center;
            e.Layout.Override.RowSelectorAppearance.TextVAlign = Infragistics.Win.VAlign.Middle;           

            //There is no wy to change the width of the RowSelectors.
            //Use a smaller font, so that 3-digit numbers will fit. 
            e.Layout.Override.RowSelectorAppearance.FontData.Name = "Small Fonts";
            e.Layout.Override.RowSelectorAppearance.FontData.SizeInPoints = 6;
        }

        //The NumbersInRowSelectors class. This class Implements a CreationFilter and
        //adds a TextUIElement to each RowSelector which displays the row number of
        //the row.
        public class NumbersInRowSelectors:Infragistics.Win.IUIElementCreationFilter
        {

            #region Implementation of IUIElementCreationFilter
            public void AfterCreateChildElements(Infragistics.Win.UIElement parent)
            {
                //Don't need to do anything here
            }
            public bool BeforeCreateChildElements(Infragistics.Win.UIElement parent)
            {
                //Declare some variables
                Infragistics.Win.TextUIElement objTextUIElement;
                Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowSelectorUIElement objRowSelectorUIElement;
                Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow objRow;
                int RowNumber;

                //Check to see if the parent is a RowSelectorUIElement. If not, 
                //we don't need to do anything
                if (parent is Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowSelectorUIElement)
                {
                    //Get the Row from the RowSelectorsUIElement
                    objRowSelectorUIElement = (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowSelectorUIElement)parent;
                    objRow = (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow)objRowSelectorUIElement.GetContext(typeof(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow));

                    //Get the Index of the Row, so we can use it as a row number. 
                    RowNumber = objRow.Index;

                    //Check to see if the TextUIElement is already created. Since
                    //The RowSelectorsUIElement never has children by default, we
                    //can just check the count. 
                    if (parent.ChildElements.Count == 0)
                    {
                        //Create a new TextUIElement and parent it to the RowSelectorUIElement
                        objTextUIElement = new Infragistics.Win.TextUIElement(parent, RowNumber.ToString());
                        parent.ChildElements.Add(objTextUIElement);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //There's already a TextUIElement here, so just set the Text
                        objTextUIElement = (Infragistics.Win.TextUIElement)parent.ChildElements[0];
                        objTextUIElement.Text = RowNumber.ToString();
                    }
                    //Position the TextUIElement into the RowSelectorUIElement
                    objTextUIElement.Rect = parent.RectInsideBorders;

                    //Return True let the grid know we handled this event. 
                    //This doesn't really do anything, since the grid
                    //does not create any child elements for this object, anyway.
                    return true;
                }

                //Return false to let the grid know we did not handle the event. 
                //This doesn't really do anything, since the grid
                //does not create any child elements for this object, anyway.
                return false;               
            }       
            #endregion
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the component with the textinputs that you are popping up when the button is selected?  That would make it easier to give you specific code.

Comment: I think u had missed out a some thing u posted a question as non visual but u gave the button( a visual component). posting a sample code is easy to help

Answer (score 0):

Create a "currently selected item" member in the class where the button and the text edit are declared.

In the button selection event listener assign the event target to this member. Then use it in the text edit event listener.
For example:

```
// It's a declaration of the member variable
private var m_current_btn:Button = null;

// It's an event listener for your button
private function on_selection_change(event:Event):void
{
   m_current_btn = event.target as Button;
   // button_x and button_y are two text edits
   button_x.text = m_current_button.x.toString();
   button_y.text = m_current_button.y.toString();
}

// Event listener to track changes in the coordinate text inputs
private function on_coordinate_textedit_change(event:Event):void
{
   if (m_current_btn != null)
   {
     m_current_btn.x = parseInt(button_x.text);
     m_current_btn.y = parseInt(button_y.text);
   }
}
```